# Smart Contract public chains, other than Ethereum mainnet

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, fees, explorers

As a DApp developer I am concern about the costs of transaction on Ethereum mainnet. Every DApp interaction with the Smart Contract is having a cost between 1$ and 50$ depending on the data size and complexity of the function performed. So I am looking for alternative Ethereum platform to run the contracts and beeing public with a chain explorer.

As far as I know, there are the following:

```
* Ethereum Classic, 10x cheaper than ETH
* RSK, on development
* Building my own chain, no chain explorer.
* Plasma.io. Is it ready to use?
* Raiden Network. Is it ready to use? Is cheaper than Ethereum mainnet?
```

Do you know any more alternatives? Thx!

Comment: Those transaction fees are quite high. Are you sure you're setting a reasonable gas price? Or is your contract just really doing that much computation?

Comment: 101 Gwei as gasPrice. Gas Used By Txn: 803560

Comment: Per https://www.ethgasstation.info/, 2 to 4 gwei are good gas prices right now. I don't know what 803560 means... typically transactions are identified by their hashes (64-character hexadecimal numbers).

Comment: The gas price can vary a lot, for example during cryptokittens most popular week 50 gwei was pretty common, weekend is lower that during weekdays. OTOH requiring about 800k of gas is a lot, did you try optimizing your contracts? Perhaps moving some computations off blockchain. Storage is quite expensive, and the ethereum blockchain never was intended to store large amounts of data. Moving storage off-blockchain can help lower the gas usage.

Comment: I have added plasma.io and Raiden Network as alternatives, but I am not sure if these sidechains are really available to use, or just under development

Comment: Also add "Stratis"

Comment: Stratis smart contracts are written in C#, right? I'm looking for a EVM alternative to Ethereum.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just testing, there are a number of public test networks: e.g. Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan.

Comment: The question is clearly about production deployment.

Comment: That wasn't (and still isn't) clear to me.

Comment: even I was thinking of this solution. Especially, ropsten is exactly like mainnet (PoW).

Answer (score 1):

partial answer but about this part of your question :

> Building my own chain, no chain explorer.

There are tools to have your own chain explorer. One of the most known is the explorer made by ethereparty you can find on [github](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer)

I haven't used it yet on a production chain, only with ganache-cli but it seems to work pretty well, even if it's not as complete as some service like etherscan.

I'm pretty sure you can connect it without much difficulty to your own chain network

Comment: Is etherscan source code available on github?

Comment: not that i know

Answer (score 1):

You can fork ethereum and run your own private chain with trillions of ETH.  Use it for your internal business.  Grab one of the open source eth blockchain explorers on github and point it at your private chain.

You can run your own semi-private consortium ethereum chain and only the nodes you authorise can connect to the network.  You can have it all private or allow partners to run a node and join the network.

In this video I show you how to deploy in 12 minutes a full consortium private ethereum chain to Azure Cloud https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsConsFaZG8

You can jump towards the end of the video to get right to the deployment part.

Comment: Do you have recommendations on deploying own chain on local machines or VMs? I have a project which would not work well with testnet or mainnet. Running it on own machines is the only option -- running it in cloud is not an option too.

Answer (score 1):

The question shows that you clearly do not want the inbuilt currency that comes with ethereum. So you have to choose an alternative blockchain.

But if you insist on using ethereum, you can use private chains and in that chain you can have an entire setup of etherchain explorer, ethstats, and some nodes with whichever consensus you like.

Answer (score 1):

> Every DApp interaction with the Smart Contract is having a cost between 1$ and 50$ depending on the data size and complexity of the function performed.

Maybe how you're architecting the smart contract can be improved. $50 cost for a method call is way too much. You're probably storing way too much data or running extremely long complex computations that are eating up the gas limit.

My suggestion is to store data off chain and only store the reference hash in the contract. You can also do complex computations off chain and only use the contract as a court system where you can provide proofs in order to verify data if someone challenges it.

> Smart Contract public chains, other than Ethereum mainnet

Other public chains are all the testnets (morden, ropsten, kovan, rinkeby), Ethereum Classic, and any fork or private chains publicly exposed.

Raiden is a state channel implementation and Plasma is a hierarchy of side chains that checkpoint to the mainchain. Both are great solutions for scaling your application once they're ready.